# PHP crypt() - Returned md5 hash

Tags: php, md5, crypt

The docs (http://php.net/manual/de/function.crypt.php) for the crypt() function show the following example for an MD5 hash:

```
$1$rasmusle$rISCgZzpwk3UhDidwXvin0
```

I understand, that "$1$" is the prefix, which contains the information, that the hash is an MD5 hash.

But how is the rest of the string an MD5 hash? Normally it should be a 32 char string (0-9, a-f), right?

I'm sure, it's a stupid question, but I still want to ask.

Comment: What you're expecting is a hexadecimal-encoded string, what you got is a base64-encoded string. They both represent the binary output of the hashing function. Also: `$ID$SALT$HASH` What you *should* be using is [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and most certainly not MD5.

Comment: @Sammitch While `password_hash()` is definitely better than `crypt()`, it's not available prior to PHP 5.5. For example, I still update multiple sites with PHP 5.3 or 5.4, and I'd definitely like to use `password_hash()` there.

Comment: @Pietu1998 - there is a [userland implementation of password_*](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for versions of PHP from 5.3.7 upwards

Comment: @Pietu1998 see Mark's link above. It's also worth noting that password_compat was written by the same guy that wrote `password_hash()`, and it's even linked to from the documentation page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Normally it should be a 32 char string (0-9, a-f), right?

That is **not correct** (at least strictly speaking). Technically, a MD5 hash is a **128 bit numeric value**. The form that you are used to is simply a **hexadecimal representation** of that number. It is often chosen because they are **easy to exchange** as strings (128-bit integers are difficult to handle. After all, a typical integer variable usually only holds 64 bit). Consider the following examples:

1. `md5("test")` in **hexadecimal** (base 16) representation: `098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6`
2. `md5("test")` in **base 64** representation: `CY9rzUYh03PK3k6DJie09g==`
3. `md5("test")` in **decimal** (base 10) representation: `12707736894140473154801792860916528374`
4. `md5("test")` in **base 27** representation (never used, just because I can and to prove my point): `ko21h9o9h8bc1hgmao4e69bn6f`

All these strings represent the same numerical value, just in different bases.

Comment: plus one for outlining that "md5" is not limited to hexadecimal representation.